# Using Gauss's Theorem in weak formulation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Can anyone see how exactly Gauss's theorem used in the following case:
In defining the weak solution to the linear elliptic equation we start with 
$$-\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}D_{j}(a_{jk}D_{k}u) + cu = f \text{   }\text{ in the bounded domain }\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$$
where $(D_{j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}})$ with the Dirichlet boundary condition
$$u|_{\partial \Omega} = \phi$$
Assuming that $u$ is a sufficiently smooth(for simplicity e.g. $u \in C^{2}(\overline{\Omega})$) solution of the above two equations. $\partial \Omega$ is sufficiently smooth, multiply the first equation by test function $v \in C_{o}^{1}(\Omega)$ and integrate over $\Omega$, then by using **Gauss's theorem**, we obtain 
$$\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\int_{\Omega}a_{jk}(D_{k}u)(D_{j}v) + \int_{\Omega}cuv = \int_{\Omega}fv$$

How exactly is the Gauss's theorem used? Thanks for any assistance. Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

They use $-\int_\Omega D_j(\ldots) v=\int_\Omega (\ldots) D_j v-\int_{\partial\Omega} (\ldots)\,v\,dS$ (the last term being zero because the test function is $0$ on the boundary). All of this kind of integral identities are analogs of the famous one-dimensional rule
$$
\int_a^b f'g=-\int_a^b fg' + \int_{\{a,b\}} fg
$$
called "integration by parts".

It seems to me that there is a mess in terminology; these types of theorems are sometimes called "Gauss", sometimes "Stokes" or "divergence" theorems; however, it should be not hard to derive it from the most well-known $\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot v=\int_{\partial\Omega} v\,dS$ or whatever you might call "Gauss Theorem".

Comment: Usually "integration by parts" in English.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks for the correction.